# How to make a moving loop with divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a website that instead of having different pages, I loop through different divs to show differen content. What I'm looking for looks a lot like what happends on this website: http://www.nexon.com/Home/Game.aspx

I would like the divs to 'fly' in from right to left and from left to right on click. I tried to understand the code from the website, but it got me very confused.

I assume there is no need to post code, since the content of my divs do not matter, but to further complete the question, this is what one of divs will look like:

```
<div>
    <img />
    <h2>Some header</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img />
    <p>More text</p>
</div>
```

So now I would like to loop through those divs in the same way as the website mentioned about does it.

Comment: I have achieved a similar effect in the past using a javascript carousel library, http://bxslider.com/ to be specific.

Comment: The website you linked to is not doing what you're saying you want to do. Each of those tabs is a separate page (game.aspx, mobilegame.aspx and ongoinglist.aspx).

Comment: @APAD1 I'm not talking about the links on the left, I'm talking about moving loop that happends in the middle.

Comment: @Phaeze That is very helpfull, thank you! Although I would like to know how I can make this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to have a "window" div that acts as a viewport to your content divs. With your content divs set to `display: inline` you can achieve the desired effect via a call to `jQuery.animate` that moves the inside of your "window" div by the width of a single content div. This is fairly error prone, not to mention tedious to code with end states, start/stop, re-loops, etc.. so it is generally recommended to use a good carousel library which there are plenty of.

Here is an example of doing it yourself

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/y9ajyyxa/)

Here are some popular carousel plugins (pretty much just googled 'jquery carousel')

[slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Accepted as answer since it was the first answer that had information so I could continue my programming.

Answer (score 1):

I used a jquery library called [JQuery Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/). It is very customizable and allows you to change div automatically or on click as you mentioned in your question. The website has very thorough documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [lbs slider](http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Simple-jQuery-Infinite-Carousel-Plugin-lbSlider.html) for that!

Put anything inside div like photo text video, It will work!

See link Below

## [See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qZNnk/981/)

[image]

**Html**

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="black"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="red">text 1</span>
            <span class="blue">text 2</span>
            <span class="blue"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" width="100"></span>
            <span class="blue"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="yellow" style="width:300px;height:200px;">
                <iframe width="300" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/z0DCGnm429Y?list=UUDw2o0zdKA_TS3BsCgbyH4A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="blue"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="green"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="#" class="slider-arrow sa-left">&lt;</a>
<a href="#" class="slider-arrow sa-right">&gt;</a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.slider-wrap {position: relative;margin: 50px auto;}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    margin:5px;
}

.slider-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sa-left {left: 10px;}
.sa-right {right: 10px;}

.black {}
.red {background: red;}
.green {background: green;}
.blue {background: blue;}
.yellow {background: yellow;}
```

**js**

```
jQuery('.slider').lbSlider({
    leftBtn: '.sa-left',
    rightBtn: '.sa-right',
    visible: 3,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlayDelay: 10
});
```